# Trying to create an ArrayList<Object> from former Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Doing this for an Android project; having issues creating An ArrayList out of what was formerly an Array of objects.

Here is what code WAS:

```
            MyReviewObject[] co = new MyReviewObject[reviews.size()];
            int index = 0;

            for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String i : reviews) {
                co[index] = new MyReviewObject(datelist.get(index),
                        reviews.get(index), items.get(index),
                        cats.get(index));
                index++;
            }

            adapter = new MyReviewAdapter(getActivity(), co);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is what I have now:

```
            ArrayList<MyReviewObject> co = new ArrayList<MyReviewObject>();


            for (String i : reviews) {
                co = new ArrayList<MyReviewObject>(datelist.add(i),reviews.add(i), items.add(i), cats.add(i));
            }

            adapter = new MyReviewAdapter(getActivity(), co);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The statement in the for loop I am having hard time converting to make work? I know I am declaring the ArrayList twice and one should go.

**EDIT**:

here is Object:

```
public class MyReviewObject {
    public String comment;
    public String date;
    public String items;
    public String cat;

    public MyReviewObject(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
        this.date = s1;
        this.comment = s2;
        this.items = s3;
        this.cat = s4;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create several arraylists, only several `MyReviewObject`:

```
for (String i : reviews) {
    MyReviewObject review = new MyReviewObject(datelist.get(i),
                    reviews.get(i), items.get(i),
                    cats.get(i));
    co.add(review);
}
```

ps: that assumes the original code works.